# Tate-Shafarevich group and its twist such that $\text{Sha}(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=0$ or some constant

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, tate-shafarevich-groups

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Let $D\in \Bbb{Z}$ be a square free integer and $E_D/\Bbb{Q}$ be its quadratic twist.

It is widely known that for all $E/\Bbb{Q}$: elliptic curve, there exists $D$ such that  $\text{rank}(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=0$. Further, it is conjectured that for 50% of $D$, $\text{rank}(E/\Bbb{Q})=0$ and for 50% of $D$, $\text{rank}(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=1$.

What is known about Tate-Shafarevich group $Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$?

Is it known that for arbitrary elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}$, does there exists a $D$ such that $\text{Sha}(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=1$ ?
If more is known, I would be appreciated if you could tell me the references.